# Titletoc - addtocontents not obeying partial toc \startcontents

Tags: titletoc

Consider the following MWE:

Two chapters. The first chapter additional injects two items to toc

a) - One via \addcontentsline
b) - A second via \addtocontents

- (a) behaves properly in respect of the partial toc
- (b) is carried through to the partial toc for chapter 2

Why is this happening?

What can I do to prevent it?

It has a number of side effects in my document which I won't elaborate here (suffice to say that I am injecting code into the toc via \addtocontents and this is repeated in subsequent chapters).

```
 \documentclass{book}
 \usepackage{titletoc}

\newcommand{\printmyminitoc}{%
\startcontents[mypart]
\printcontents[mypart]{}{1}[4]{}
}%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\printmyminitoc
\section{Sec1}
\subsection{Subsec1}
\subsection{Subsec2}
\section{Sec2}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{added via addcontentsline}
 \addtocontents{toc}{{added via addtocontents\endgraf}}

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\printmyminitoc
\section{Sec1}
\subsection{Subsec1}
\subsection{Subsec2}
\section{Sec2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am assuming that because nobody is responding here that this is a bug to be reported. Just wanted to check I am not doing something stupid.